# How to write to Local MMS DB Kitkat after receiving it?

Tags: android, mms, android-4.4-kitkat

In the KitKat version of Android, how do you write an MMS message to the local MMS database after receiving it (After you make your app the Default SMS app)?  The documentation and upgrade blogs explain how to receive the MMS message but I can't find any information anywhere on how to write this received MMS to the local MMS database.

Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write to the database any more (unless you are default app). You need to use new SMS Provider and API. [See docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-sms-provider)

Comment: just as a small correction, you can write to it just your app needs to be the default sms app

Comment: Thanks for the replies. i know we can write to the database if default, but can't find any documentation on how to do this. How and what do you write to the MMS database?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748209/receive-mms-messages-in-android-kitkat

Comment: Hey @Marcin, If you are the default app how do you then write to the local MMS DB in KitKat?